# How to get object type SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get an object which has the type SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement.
Can someone show me an example (html) where the returned (created) output is of type SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement?

More details on this type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh973367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feFuncR");
alert(el instanceof SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement);
```

So, el implements SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement interface.

Comment: Interesting. So basically I can use any element of type feFuncA,B,G and R to apply the SVGComponentTransferFunctionElement properties of it. Solves, my issue. Thanks!